# Venn diagram for conditional probability property of Independent Events

Tags: probability

In my maths schoolbook there is this property for independent events:

> p(A|B) = p(A)
>
> p(B|A) = p(B)

But I can't imagine how this is possible. How would you draw a Venn diagram that follows this property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a diagram that illustrates independence, where probability means "area". 
 Here $P(A)$ is the proportion of the square that is colored yellow, while $P(A\mid B)$ is the proportion of the green stripe that is colored yellow. These two proportions are the same (approximately 1/3).

[image]

Comment: So, in this case, P(A∩B) = P(A|B)*P(B) because P(A|B) = P(A) ? But, if P(A|B) is P(A), then what is the rest of the yellow stripe?

Comment: Oh I see! Because P(A|B) is one third of P(B) but P(A) is also one third of 1 (or the total area), right?

Comment: @SilenceOnTheWire Yes, this is how to interpret the diagram.

Comment: Alright, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The events $A$ and $B$ are independent if
$$
P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B).
$$
The conditional probability of the event $A$ given the event $B$ is defined by
$$
P(A\mid B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}
$$
provided that $P(B)>0$. So we have that
$$
P(A\mid B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}=\frac{P(A)P(B)}{P(B)}=P(A)
$$
if $A$ and $B$ are independent. Analogously, $P(B\mid A)=P(B)$. So we see that this property holds if and only if the events $A$ and $B$ are independent. This property can be taken as a definition of the independence.

Comment: But how is this possible? How is it possible that P(something)/P(B) = P(something)? In my view, this can only happen if P(B) = 1, right?

Comment: Wait, actually no, because multiplying P(B) and dividing by it cancel each other.

Comment: It is not like that. The property states that if two events $A$ and $B$ are independent, then $P(A\cap B)/P(B)=P(A)$. But this is true because $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$ if $A$ and $B$ are independent.