# How can we show independence in venn diagram?

Tags: probability, independence

Is there any specific feature in probability of independent events that can be shown in its Venn diagram? or maybe the diagram just and only depends on the problem?

In another words, is it possible to know if events are independent just by their Venn diagram?

I found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1947983) Q&A in SE, but didn't help much.

Comment: Venn diagrams are topological: their sizes do not convey numerical values while the picture you link to does.  So Venn diagrams cannot convey the concept of independence though in some cases they can convey mutual exclusivity

Comment: Didn't help much? Sorry then, but I don't think there is anything better.

Comment: @Henry thanks, and can't they show independence with having and not having intersections either?

Comment: Independence in probability is a property about sigma-algebras (generated by the events/random variables) under a certain probability measure. Somethings are independent under one particular probability, but they may be dependent under another probability. Venn Diagram is usually used to show some set relationship

Comment: @drhab well I don't understand it cuz it's just one example...

Comment: In a Venn-diagram you can go for (you don't have to): size of area linked with event corresponds with probability of event. In that context independence of events appears also in the diagram. This comes forward in the link in your question.

Comment: Your link shows a very simple exmp. With explanation, it might or might not be helpful in visualizing independence. As you begin the study of probability, it is important to distinguish between the _logical_ concept of _disjointness,_ which can easily be shown in a Venn Diagram, and the _probability_ concept of _independence_, which is not easily shown in a Venn Diagram. // ...

Comment: ... If I draw 2 balls from an urn, then events "both balls red" and "both balls black" are obviously disjoint. In order to discuss whether these events are _independent,_ I need probability info. (How many balls of each color in urn? Drawn at random? Drawn with or w/o replacement? Etc.) // People have tried various schemes of representing independence in "modified Venn Diagrams," where areas represent probabilities. To date none of these schemes has become generally popular. I guess because way too much explanation is required.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can one infer independence by simple reasoning/intuition?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1898596/can-one-infer-independence-by-simple-reasoning-intuition)

Comment: @bclc already checked that. Was not my answer.

Comment: @parvin k XD $ \ $